# Regex Search for entire column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to **EXTRACT** B0153R2A9I from urls in a column in dataframe.
e.g. 'http://www.example.com/zs/B0153R2A9I'

I found this code in a reddit group -

```
import re
search = re.search(r'B[A-Z0-9]{9}', url)
print(search.group(0))
```

While this appears to work for one link, when I try to apply this for a column like this -

```
import re
df['code'] = re.search(r'B[A-Z0-9]{9}', "", df['pro_link'])
```

df['pro_link'] column has all the links. df['code'] is the new column to be created.

I get this error
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['code'] = df['pro_link'].str.extract(r'/(B[A-Z0-9]{9})$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5QGNf6/2). *Details*:

- `/` -  a `/` char
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `B` - a `B` char
  - `[A-Z0-9]{9}` - nine ASCII uppercase letters or digits
- `)` - end of the capturing group (it is necessary for `Series.str.extract` to actually return anything)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I am sorry I meant Extract not strip. Just edited.

Comment: @Santoo I updated the code, demo link and pattern explanation in the answer.

Comment: What @WiktorStribiżew is using here is a pandas [`.str` the string accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) with [the `extract` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#extracting-substrings).

Comment: Thanks @wiktor. There were some links with '/' towards the end and continuing with other text. I used r'B[A-Z0-9]{9}' and it appears to work.

Comment: @Santoo Then you may use `r'/(B[A-Z0-9]{9})(?:/|$)'`, where `(?:/|$)` matches either `/` or end of string.

Comment: @Wiktor. Amazing. Thank you. I am going to start learning about regex101.com.  Truly appreciate.

Comment: @Santoo Surely this answer should be `df['code'] = df['pro_link'].str.extract...`.